# Office 2016 applications hang after remote desktop usage

Tags: remote-desktop, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2016, microsoft-onenote-2016, remmina

Observed with Excel and OneNote. After watching them via Remmina Remote desktop, their windows become non-responsive and applications hang.

How to fix? May be disable animations or any smarteness to detect RDS?

Comment: Try in Properties of Excel.exe to set Compatibility mode to "Windows 7".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to Disable hardware graphics acceleration.

There should be a checkbox in the Advanced menu:

[image: advanced menu]

Or in the Local Group Policy Editor, select the Miscellaneous node of the Microsoft Office 2016 or Microsoft Office 2013 tree. You should be able to toggle the option there.